# How would i give a line break into a list?

Tags: python, discord.py

i want to give a line break on a list to make from this [image]

to this

[image]

Here is the code

````
    @commands.command() #PLAYERS INFO
    async def players(self,ctx,ADD,NUM):
        with SampClient(address=ADD, port=NUM) as client:
            players = [client.name for client in client.get_server_clients()]
            lst = [f'{players}']
            joined = '\n'.join(lst)    
            await ctx.send(f'```{joined}```')
````

Comment: Do you still want the list to be a list? Or just printed out on a new line?

Answer (score 3):

Simply join the list with newline as the delimiter

```py
lst = ['list of names']
joined = '\n'.join(lst) # send this
```